# Python selenium how to select something from a dropdown box

Tags: python

I am trying to make a quick bot to get kumon answers and it logs in just fine in able to get anything you need to select something from a dropdown box. This is what I have

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select



import time

PATH = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.kumon.com/AnswerBook/AnswerBookLogin.aspx")
acc = driver.find_element_by_id("txtStudentID")
name = driver.find_element_by_id("txtPassword")
#select = driver.find_element_by_name("drpLevel")
acc.send_keys("id")
name.send_keys("pass")
name.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
#time.sleep(1)
driver.implicitly_wait(4)
dropA = driver.find_element_by_id("drpLevel")
dropA.select_by_visible_text('G')
```

but it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx", line 25, in <module>
    dropA.select_by_visible_text('G')
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'select_by_visible_text'
```

The html code is [image: Was not able to copy and paste it]

I don't know what is causing this but if anyone can help me thanks!

Comment: Provide complete HTML code as text not image. Provide more code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: i am not able to copy and paste it